# how to update Table using SqliteManager in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlitemanager

I am using [SqliteManager](https://github.com/anthonyly/SQLiteManager) to add data in database.

I have to update a table with the query below but it doesn't updating table data.

```
SQLiteManager.sharedInstance().executeQuery("UPDATE Invoice SET is_void = '1',void_comment ='\(txtComment.text)',void_date = '\(currentDateTime)' WHERE invoice_id = '\(inVoiceNumber)'")
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this query or how can I check if the data is updated?

**Structure of table Invoice**

```
CREATE TABLE [Invoice]
(
   [is_void] INT,
   [void_comment] NVARCHAR(500),
   [void_date] NVARCHAR(50),
   [invoice_id] BIGINT,
)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?, also show us the structure of `Invoice` table.

Comment: @NiravD i update question with demo structure.

Comment: None of the columns listed in the query seem to match the table you posted.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry for that.i am updating question

Comment: @rmaddy please check updated question

Comment: Don't quote numeric values in the query. Better, properly bind values into the query (assuming SqliteManager supports that).

Comment: i am not getting error.

Comment: @rmaddy means is_void = strvalue. like this?

Comment: No. `is_void = 1` instead of `is_void = '1'`. Remove the quotes from any numeric value.

Comment: Also from `invoice_id = inVoiceNumber`

Comment: @rmaddy Yes this is working.but invoice number id dynamic.how to format in query

Comment: Can you show us the code how you are assigning value in `inVoiceNumber` variable.

Comment: var tags = 0
tags = Int(sender.tag)
inVoiceNumber = (arrSales[tags].valueForKey("invoice_id") as! String)

Comment: @NiravD i want to say as you said take invoice_id = 1. but this is dynamic

Comment: @rmaddy grateful for your guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamic `inVoiceNumber`, Just pass like this no nee to add single quote.

```
var inVoiceNumber = Int(arrSales[tags].valueForKey("invoice_id") as! String)
SQLiteManager.sharedInstance().executeQuery("UPDATE Invoice SET is_void = 1,void_comment ='\(txtComment.text)',void_date = '\(currentDateTime)' WHERE invoice_id = \(inVoiceNumber)")
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)

Comment: May i ask one more thing?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Yes what is it?

Comment: when i insert data it is inserting.i can check in log. but in table some time data not display

Comment: Are you getting error if data is not insert in table, also show the code that you have used for inserting records.

Comment: i am adding invoicenumber at cellforrowatindexpath
inVoiceNumber              = (dic["invoice_num"]   as? String)!
when i use this value .query not working

Comment: Query : UPDATE Invoice SET is_void = 1 ,void_comment ='Optional("")',void_date = '2016-09-14 16:15:11' WHERE invoice_id = 3)

Comment: Sorry for late response may be the issue is with `void_comment ='Optional("")'` it should not contain optional like this in query.